# Generate an undirected graph by probability on edges in R

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

Is there an R function for generating an undirected graph with probability on edges? I've tried to generate a nonparanormal data set by constructing the adjacency matrix (precision matrix) [see appendix]. First of all, I should generate a random graph, which the of pairwise edges (i,j) follows the normal probability density function. the `igraph` package includes the `sample_fitness` and `sample_degseq` functions, which apply probabilities on the degree of each vertex, but not on the existence of edges between i and j vertices.
Thank you all.

[image: Liu, Lafferty and Wasserman (2009)].

```
library(MASS)
library(Matrix)
library(philentropy)
library(qgraph)
library(igraph)
library(huge)
d=10
tmp=matrix(runif(2*d,0,0.5),d,2)
tmp=2*tmp
L=distance(tmp,method="euclidean")
s=0.125
prob=(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(L^2)/2*s)
prob=mat2vec(prob)
degs<-sample(0:(length(prob)-1),d,replace=TRUE,prob=prob)
for(i in 1:d){
if (degs[i]>4){degs[i]=4}
}
degs
if(sum(degs)%%2!=0){degs[1]<-degs[1]+1}
degs
g4 <-sample_degseq(degs,method="vl")
all(degree(g4)==degs)
plot(g4)
theta=as_adjacency_matrix(g4,type="both")
for(j in 1:d){
for(i in 1:d){
if(theta[i,j]==0)
omega[i,j]=0
else
omega[i,j]=0.245
}
}
diag(omega)=1
```

Comment: I wonder from which library `distances, mat2vec` come from.

Comment: Note prob=dnorm(L, 0, sqrt(s)) * sqrt(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runif` along with `prob` to generate your random network, e.g.,

```
adjmat <- prob
adjmat[] <- runif(length(prob))
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(
  +(as.matrix(adjmat) <= as.matrix(prob)) - diag(d),
  mode = "undirected"
)
```

and the network with ***probabilistic*** edges are shown as, for example

[image]

Comment: The 'prob' is not an adjancency matrix, it's supposed to be the probability of the existence an edge between two nodes. The question is, first, how to generate a graph by probability on edges. Next, restrict the max degree of the graph to be four. Finally, covert the graph to an adjancency matrix. Thanks.

Comment: @HamidAghabozorgi `prob` is not an adjacency matrix. I just use it with `runif` to see if  the edge (i,j) should be assigned. If you run my code each time, you will see different adjacency between node, since `runif` gives a random edge assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create the required matrix.
Source:  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608017v1

Lets take as an example:

```
g <- sample_gnm(10, 20)
degree(g)
```

The next step is to remove random edges until all nodes have degree 4 or less.

```
g1 <- g
while (max(degree(g1)) > max_deg) {
  vvv <- V(g1)[which(degree(g1) > max_deg)]
  g1  <- g1 - sample(incident(g1, vvv), 1)
}
degree(g1)
dev.new(); plot(g2, layout=layout_in_circle)
```

Output:

```
[1] 2 6 3 7 4 5 2 1 5 5 - degrees g
[1] 1 3 3 2 4 4 4 3 2 2 - degrees g1
```